# Django getting database fields with one query

Tags: django, django-models

I have a few models in django (`User(standard)`, `Member(extended user)`, `Calculations`, `Subscription`, `Type`) as follows :

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    ..........

class Calculations(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    .....

class Type(models.Model):
    limit = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    default = models.BooleanField()


class Subscription(models.Model):
    started = models.DateField()
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    member = models.OneToOneField(Member)
```

Thus,

- `Calculations` is connected to `User` with `ForeignKey`
- `Member` is also connected to `user` with `ForeignKey`
- `Subscriptions` is connected to `Member` and with `Type` with `ForeignKey`

In my view I want to query the database and to access information from all those models.

Thus I want all members except the currently logged in, and I want to get the number of the calculations and the type of the subscription.

I'm trying to do it with one query.

I tried something like :

```
@login_required
def members(request):
    // That's how I get all information about user and members, but I also need the calculation and subscription
    members_list = Member.objects.select_related('user').all().exclude(user=request.user)
    context = {'members': members_list}
    return render(request, 'master/members.html', context)
```

Any advice how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access all elements from related Models.

```
qv = Member.objects.exclude(user=request.user).values('user__subscription__started', 'user', 'user__calculations__user')
```

Comment: I get an error : `Cannot resolve keyword 'calculations' into field. Choices are: active, address, city, country, country_id, id, language, language_id, main_email, match_code, member, mobile, name, number, parent, parent_id, postcode, subscription, telephone, user, user_id`

Comment: Yes, that way you should make query.

Comment: Change the answer and I'm going to accept it..And thanks ;)

Comment: Done. Nice to help you.